# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) error while inserting data

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into a postgres table. But I get the below error.
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character(1)

I have checked the data in the csv file. There are 2 columns in the file which should have length as 1, but both the column values do not exceed the length of 1.

Below is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE staging.incident (
    incident_id int8 NOT NULL,
    machine_type text NULL,
    serial_nbr text NULL,
    country_code bpchar(2) NULL,
    claim_nbr text NULL,
    service_delivery_type bpchar(3) NULL,
    entitlement_type bpchar(3) NULL,
    claim_create_ts timestamp NULL,
    claim_status bpchar(2) NULL,
    claim_close_ts timestamp NULL,
    close_code text NULL,
    severity bpchar(1) NULL,
    res_type_desc text NULL,
    res_cat_desc text NULL,
    res_prob_desc text NULL,
    res_rslt_desc text NULL,
    call_rcvd_type bpchar(1) NULL,
    vendor_id text NULL,
    cust_prob text NULL,
    error_code text NULL
);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to create a [mre].

Comment: An example of the data in the CSV file would be useful. The error is pretty specific so there is something in the columns that is exceeding a single character. This could be a leading space(trailing spaces are truncated) or a hidden character.  It is also possible you have a one off situation where the incoming fields are not lining up with the table fields.

Comment: 509432703,"20HE","PF12Z0CC","CZ","40DH5F7","IOR","WAR","2021-05-06 00:02:58.0","SS",,"ONS","3","LENOVO","HARDWARE SUPPORT","SYSTEMBOARD","","E","","","CZ25WORD"
509434960,"20QD","PF1T7H7G","SE","40DH6M3","CCR","WAR","2021-05-06 10:52:59.0","HF",,,"3","","","","","V","","",""
508422538,"40AN","ZJT05RNR","US","40C3K9L","IOR","WAR","2020-08-21 11:19:15.0","CA","2021-05-07 08:05:16.0","CAN","3","","","","","V","","",""
509439023,"20L7","PC0XHZ0L","GB","CLDTFWC","CCR","WAR","2021-05-06 12:08:24.0","XI",,"DEP","3","LENOVO","HARDWARE SUPPORT","SYSTEMBOARD","","","","",""

Comment: I tried inserting the data into SQL server table with the same structure. It worked fine.

Comment: Please [edit] the data into the question, and add the Python code used to perform the insertion.